# Reactjs Routing from SideBar Component Doesnt Render Anything

Tags: reactjs

I hope everybody's doing fine and safe. I've been busy with my hobby project last recently. I've two component one named Home component other one is the Sidebar component

```
function Sidebar() {
    const [videos, setVideos] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const response = await fetch(
                "http://192.168.0.178:4000/videos"
            );
            const data = await response.json();
            setVideos(data);
        };

        fetchData();
    }, [])
    return (

        <div className="sidebar">


            <Col sm={3} className="side">

                {videos.slice(0, 4).map(video =>
                    <Card key={video.id}>
                        <Card.Header>{video.duration}</Card.Header>
                        <Card.Img variant="top" src={`http://192.168.0.178:4000${video.poster}`} className="imgside" />
                        <Card.Body className="cbody">

                             <Link to={`/player/${video.id}`}>
                                <Card.Text>
                                    {video.name}
                                </Card.Text>
                            </Link> 

                        </Card.Body>
                    </Card>

                )}


            </Col>
        </div>
    )

}

export default Sidebar;
```

And i have my Home component as below;

```
export default class Home extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            videos: []
        };
    }
    async componentDidMount() {
        try {
            const response = await fetch('http://192.168.0.178:4000/videos');
            const data = await response.json();
            this.setState({ videos: [...data] });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    

    render() {
    


    
        return (
            <div className='homepage'>

                <Container fluid>
                    <Row>
                        <Col sm={12}>

                            <CardDeck>
                                {this.state.videos.slice(0, 3).map(video =>
                                    <Card style={{ width: '25rem', color: '#000' }} key={video.id}>
                                        <Card.Img variant="top" src={`http://192.168.0.178:4000${video.poster}`} />
                                        <Card.Body>
                                            <Card.Title>{video.duration}</Card.Title>
                                            <Card.Text>
                                                {video.name}
                                            </Card.Text>
                                            <Link to={`/player/${video.id}`}>
                                                <Button variant="primary">IZLE</Button>
                                            </Link>
                                        </Card.Body>
                                    </Card>

                                )}

                            </CardDeck>
                        </Col>

                    </Row>



                    <Row>
                        <Col sm={12}>
                            <CardDeck>

                                {this.state.videos.slice(7, 10).map(video =>
                                    <Card style={{ width: '25rem', color: '#000' }} key={video.id}>
                                        <Card.Img variant="top" src={`http://192.168.0.178:4000${video.poster}`} />
                                        <Card.Body>
                                            <Card.Title>{video.duration}</Card.Title>
                                            <Card.Text>
                                                {video.name}
                                            </Card.Text>
                                            <Link to={`/player/${video.id}`}>
                                                <Button variant="primary">IZLE</Button>
                                            </Link>
                                        </Card.Body>
                                    </Card>
                                )}

                            </CardDeck>


                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Container>




            </div>

        )
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to go to my player view from home component it does work but however when i tried to player view from my sidebar it just change the url but doesnt render the view. Briefly the sidebar is rendered from the app.js component cause i'd love the have it in my player view and home view but linking is not workin from both view. Does anybody knows what could be the issue Thanks!

Below you can see my app component

```
function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
          <header className='App-header'>
          <Navigation/>
          </header>
          <Sidebar/>
          <Router>
            <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home}></Route>
            <Route path="/player/:id" component={Player}></Route>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
        </div>
    );
}
```

```
export default class Player extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            videoId: this.props.match.params.id,
            videoData: [],
        };
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        try {
            const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:4000/video/${this.state.videoId}`);
            const data = await res.json();
            this.setState({ videoData: data });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="player">
                <header className="player-header">
                <h1>SIKIS</h1>
                </header>
                <video controls autoPlay>
                        <source src={`http://localhost:4000/video/${this.state.videoId}`} type="video/mp4"></source>
                    </video>
                    <h1>{ this.state.videoData.name }</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you are using a `Link` outside `Router`
Your Home page is rendered within a Router component. But your Sidebar is outside of the Router.

Comment: Hello Ravindu, i appreciate for your suggestion. I've tried that way as you said as well but then it only works once and afterwards when i click it, the url is changing now the view thanks

Comment: Yeap i've added it